# Using Eclipse as an Editor (like Coda or Vim)

Tags: eclipse, vim, pydev, coda

There is a Python project created by using Vim and Coda which doesn't include any editor specific file. I'm used to use Eclipse as an editor so I want to work on this project using Eclipse. But I don't know how to do it without to create a new project in Eclipse or without importing it. Because I don't want to get a copy of these files. I just want to edit like I can do in Coda or Vim.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'm using OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Eclipse do File->Open and it will load the file even if not in a project

From the command line on my machine the expected open -a Eclipse.app t.py does not work as Eclipse has not registered itself as being able to associate Python script files (it also fails to open java files so is Eclipse not pydev setup)